# Subset list with For cycle

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

I have to subset this "plt" list. 
"Plt" is a list of GPS points, with date and time.
"Labels" is a list of all trips in the day, with start and end time.

I would take the point in row 1 from `labels$Start` and the point in row 1 from `labels$End`, search these values in `plt$Data_Time` column and subset all rows between the Start value and the End value.

```html
> str(labels)
'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Date_ST: Factor w/ 5 levels "2008/04/28","2008/04/29",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
 $ Time_ST: Factor w/ 15 levels "01:27:05","01:33:29",..: 13 15 4 10 1 7 8 12 2 11
 $ Date_ET: Factor w/ 5 levels "2008/04/28","2008/04/29",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
 $ Time_ET: Factor w/ 15 levels "01:35:25","01:41:11",..: 13 15 3 10 1 5 6 12 2 9
 $ Mode   : Factor w/ 2 levels "subway","walk": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ ID     : int  1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15
 $ Start  : chr  "2008/04/28 11:27:42" "2008/04/28 11:42:56" "2008/04/29 01:38:21" "2008/04/29 01:57:55" ...
 $ End    : chr  "2008/04/28 11:27:58" "2008/04/28 11:50:10" "2008/04/29 01:41:28" "2008/04/29 02:03:28" ...
 
 > str(plt)
'data.frame': 4377 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Lat      : num  40.1 40.1 40.1 40.1 40.1 ...
 $ Long     : num  116 116 116 116 116 ...
 $ X0       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Alt      : int  492 492 491 491 491 490 490 490 489 489 ...
 $ n.days   : num  39589 39589 39589 39589 39589 ...
 $ Date     : Factor w/ 5 levels "2008-05-21","2008-04-28",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Time     : Factor w/ 2955 levels "01:33:29","01:33:30",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ID       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Data_Time: chr  "2008-05-21 01:33:29" "2008-05-21 01:33:30" "2008-05-21 01:33:31" "2008-05-21 01:33:33" ...
```

```html
head(plt)
       Lat     Long X0 Alt   n.days       Date     Time ID           Data_Time
1 40.07045 116.3130  0 492 39589.06 2008-05-21 01:33:29  1 2008-05-21 01:33:29
2 40.07045 116.3133  0 492 39589.06 2008-05-21 01:33:30  2 2008-05-21 01:33:30
3 40.07050 116.3131  0 491 39589.06 2008-05-21 01:33:31  3 2008-05-21 01:33:31
4 40.07052 116.3130  0 491 39589.06 2008-05-21 01:33:33  4 2008-05-21 01:33:33
5 40.07050 116.3129  0 491 39589.06 2008-05-21 01:33:35  5 2008-05-21 01:33:35
6 40.07047 116.3129  0 490 39589.07 2008-05-21 01:33:37  6 2008-05-21 01:33:37

labels
      Date_ST  Time_ST    Date_ET  Time_ET Mode ID               Start                 End
1  2008/04/28 11:27:42 2008/04/28 11:27:58 walk  1 2008/04/28 11:27:42 2008/04/28 11:27:58
3  2008/04/28 11:42:56 2008/04/28 11:50:10 walk  3 2008/04/28 11:42:56 2008/04/28 11:50:10
4  2008/04/29 01:38:21 2008/04/29 01:41:28 walk  4 2008/04/29 01:38:21 2008/04/29 01:41:28
6  2008/04/29 01:57:55 2008/04/29 02:03:28 walk  6 2008/04/29 01:57:55 2008/04/29 02:03:28
7  2008/05/12 01:27:05 2008/05/12 01:35:25 walk  7 2008/05/12 01:27:05 2008/05/12 01:35:25
9  2008/05/12 01:51:11 2008/05/12 01:55:35 walk  9 2008/05/12 01:51:11 2008/05/12 01:55:35
```

I need to do it for each row, so I have thought to use a for cycle.
In the end, I want to keep only the column 1 and 2 (Lat and Long).

```html
for(i in 1:nrow(labels)) {
  a = labels$Start[i] #prendo coord inizio/fine percorso
  b = labels$End[i] 
  
  k = plt[plt$Data_Time >= a & plt$Data_Time < b, ]
  LatLong = k[1:2]
  head(LatLong)
  write.table(LatLong, "~/Desktop/LatLongTrip.txt", sep="\t")
```

Unfortunately, the result is:

```html
> k = plt[plt$Data_Time >= b & plt$Data_Time < a, ]
> k
[1] Lat       Long      X0        Alt       n.days    Date      Time      ID        Data_Time
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

In reality, there are some rows between these two values, could you help me, please?

Comment: Hi your date times need to be formatted as such, at the moment they are mainly strings (see `Data_Time` class is "chr" = character in the str call) you might want to check out `?as.POSIXct` to format them so that R knows they are dates

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for cycle :)
Here:

First make sure to have library sqldf

Then, setting up a mock data example:

```
fechasInicioYFin <- data.frame(
  fechasInicio = as.POSIXct(c('2016-08-19 10:00','2016-08-25 15:00','2016-09-15 15:00','2016-07-20 11:00')),
  fechasFin = as.POSIXct(c('2016-08-19 14:00','2016-08-25 18:00','2016-09-15 19:00','2016-07-20 16:00'))

  )

dataConFecha <- data.frame(num1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), num2 = c(11:16), 
                           fechas =  as.POSIXct(c('2016-08-19 12:00','2016-08-25 16:00','2016-09-15 16:00','2016-07-20 13:00',
                                                  '2016-08-19 13:00','2016-09-15 17:00'))
                             )
```

Now just join them by the date column and select only the columns that you are interested:

```
sqldf("select a.*,b.fechasInicio,b.fechasFin from dataConFecha as a join fechasInicioYFin as b on
  a.fechas between b.fechasInicio and b.fechasFin")
```

**using "between" sql statement instead of >= and <=, as suggested by @G. Grothendieck

The output should be something like this:[image: sqlJoin Result]

As you can see, the data is now basically grouped by beginning date and ending date.